# SEO Impact of Returning an Empty Response on HEAD Requests

Tags: seo, request, bots, head

I'm working a site that frequently gets floods of head requests from IPs in the Amazon cloud. I feel very confident based on the patterns that they access that they are up to no good. To combat this I'm considering returning an empty response on all HEAD requests, however I don't want to accidentally impact the rankings on this site.

Is anyone aware of search engines that legitimately use HEAD requests as part of the indexing process that might be affected by this change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hum,

Normally, if the ips you have spotted is not bots from search engines, they'll no impacts. If you have ban a big range of ips and with that legitimate users, you can have a bounce ratios to get higher and so it can theoretically impact your website seo performance. Odds are pretty small.

Nevertheless, the best implementation is to return a forbidden header ('HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden'), it'll not draw ressources and it'll be cleaner.

Comment: are you aware of any legitimate crawlers or spiders that use HEAD requests? Have you ever seen Googlebot use them?

Comment: yeah of course, they try to not load all the body if it's not necessary (etag, chabge date..) Moreover, googlebot try to find how you server react for example for 404, they surely do deep analysis of head to maintain their indexes.